# iOS EAAccessory - Unsupported legacy device

Tags: ios, bluetooth

When trying to pair the Bluetooth from iOS mobile using EAAccessory to another peripheral then I am getting error. The error says "Unsupported Legacy Device" with description "Please go to Settings to pair with *****". The same code works very well for one kind of peripherals but doesn't work for another kind. Data transition works fine if I pair the device to peripheral from iPhone Settings but it just doesn't work using in-app pairing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What sort of device is it?  Is it supported by the accessory framework?

Comment: @Paukw11- I am not sure how to check if a peripheral is supported by accessory framework or not. The device has MFI chip and my app works fine if i do the pairing through Settings screen

Comment: Then it sounds like you have your answer right there in the error; This device is unsupported for pairing in-app.  You will need to contact the device manufacturer for more details.

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, Apple never documented anything about not supporting EAAccessory to peripheral  with BT Classic if the it has MFI chip. I am not able to see any documentation about the error I saw. Without evidence I can't go to manufacture as well.

Comment: you can't publish an app to the App Store that uses an MFi program peripheral without the support of the MFi license holder/manufacturer so I don't see why you can't approach the manufacturer for information and/or contact Apple for support